# How do you Block user-agents from your CDN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-agent

I have a wordpress site and use a mobile plugin to display a mobile version for mobile devices.

I also have parts of my site using Amazon Cloudfront which seems to be stuffing up the detection of user-agents.

Does anyone know how to block user-agents within Amazon CDN?

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom URLs to map the CDN URLs to your domain:

- [Virtual Hosting Custom URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs)

Then add a `robots.txt` file on your server to block user agents, such as this one:

- [Amazon robot](http://www.amazon.com/robots.txt)